# How to parse specific string from site HTML

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup, html-parsing, text-parsing

I found from Stackoverflow that I can parse websites using Jsoup easily.

For example, I can write following codes to parse newsHeadlines from wikipedia website.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");
```

Here comes my question.
If I'd like to parse this website https://campusoperations.temple.edu/parking-transportation/garages-lots?campus=4, grab parking lots' address strings and put into string variables, so I finally have string variables like

```
String fifteenStreetLot = "1855 N. 15th Street Philadelphia, PA 19122"
String bellGarage = "1840 N. 11th Street Philadelphia, PA 19122"
```

What codes should I write?

It seems like I can't find that corresponding HTML element when I opened the html file by using chrome's More Tools > Developer Tools.

For your better understanding,
I don't want to manually type "1855 N. 15th Street Philadelphia, PA 19122". I want to have that string parsed from the website and finally have a string: `String fifteenStreetLot = "1855 N. 15th Street Philadelphia, PA 19122";`

Answer (score 1):

At first I can see on your link the next:

```
<div class="thoroughfare">1840 N. 11th Street</div>
<div class="addressfield-container-inline locality-block country-US"><span class="locality">Philadelphia</span>, <span class="state">PA</span> <span class="postal-code">19122</span></div>
```

With css selectors like

```
div.thoroughfare
```

and

```
div.adressfield-container-inline
```

you can get parts of what you need.